# Is there a workaround when Xdebug returns a 404 Not Found error when downloading a dll?

Tags: xdebug

I ran the xdebug wizard after pasting in the php info details for (8.0.26) and after it does the analysis it instructs me to

"Download php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.0-vs16.dll"

When I click on the link I receive a blank page with a 404 Not Found error message.  Is there a another location where I can find this DLL

Answer (score 1):

The wizard gave you [the wrong link](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1955), you can download the dll here:

http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-3.0.3-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the wizard. From Xdebug 3.2, 32-bit builds of Xdebug on Windows are no longer supported, and the information that you pasted into the wizard indicated that you're still using a 32-bit version of PHP.

Xdebug's wizard should have told you that. I will update the wizard to make this clear, but your only solution is to switch to a 64-bit build of PHP on Windows.

Comment: Thanks you, Derick for the clarification